# How do I call an ArrayList method from another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm in the process of creating a text UI for an `ArrayList` class, and I'm trying to create the methods in the second class that call the `ArrayList` methods. However when I'm trying to call a method that adds an object into the `ArrayList`, I'm getting an error.

```
private void addStudent()
{
    labClass.enrollStudent();
}
```

I'm trying to call the method `enrollStudent()` from the `labClass` class, but it's saying

> method enrollStudent cannot be applied to given types

What exactly do I need to do to call this method? It's something I haven't done before.

Here's the full source code for the same class if it's needed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class TextUI
{

    private Scanner myScanner;
    private LabClass labClass;

    public TextUI()
    {
        myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        createLabClass();
    }

    public void menu()
    {
        int command = -1;
        while(command != 0)
        {
            displayMenu();
            command = getCommand();
            execute(command);
        }
    }

    public void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("Select command: ");
        System.out.println("    Display Full Class Details: 1");
        System.out.println("    Add Student: 2");
        System.out.println("    Find Student by Name: 3");
        System.out.println("    Set Instructor: 4");
        System.out.println("    Set Room Mumber: 5");
        System.out.println("    Set Time and Day: 6");
        System.out.println("    Remove Student: 7");
        System.out.println("    Get Class Size: 8");
        System.out.println("    Terminate Program: 0");
    }

    private void createLabClass()
    {
        LabClass labClass = new LabClass();
    }

    private int getCommand()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter command: ");
        int command = myScanner.nextInt();
        return command;
    }

    private void execute(int command)
    {
        if(command == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Terminating program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        if(command == 8)
        {
            System.out.println("The class size is: " + getClassSize());
        }
    }

    private int getClassSize()
    {
        return labClass.getNumberOfStudents();
    }

    private void addStudent()
    {
        labClass.enrollStudent();
    }
}
```

Here's the code for LabClass.enrollStudent

```
/**
 * Add a student to this LabClass.
 * @param newStudent the student object to be enrolled
 */
public void enrollStudent(Student newStudent)
{
    students.add(newStudent);
}
```

addStudent code

```
private void execute(int command)
{
    if(command == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Terminating program...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(command == 1)
    {
        labClass.getLabClass();
    } 
    else if(command == 2)
    {
        addStudent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for LabClass as well? Specifically the enrollStudent method?

Comment: You must be calling the enrollStudent method with short arguments. Check if enrollStudent accepts any parameters.

Comment: Don't forget to change `LabClass labClass = new LabClass();` to `labClass = new LabClass();`

Comment: So I've removed the leading LabClass, what do I need to do to call the method?

Comment: @J.Brown please check my new answer and see if that helps clear it up for you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're overwriting your class variable `labClass` In your createLabClass method, remove the leading `LabClass`. It should look like this

```
private void createLabClass()
{
    labClass = new LabClass();
}
```

I think what is happening is that you are attempting to access `labClass.enrollStudent();` from your class variable, which is never instantiated. Instead, you were instantiating a local version of it that was never used

Then, when it comes to your LabClass implementation, something like this should suffice

```
public class LabClass() {
    private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public void enrollStudent(Student newStudent) {
        students.add(newStudent);
    }
}
```

Obviously, you may have more in your class, but without knowledge of it, I wrote it as short and simple as possible

Answer (score 1):

So in addition to what @**Brandon** & @**Denis** said, it turned out that you are calling the enrollStudent method with no parameters. You need to pass in a `Student` object to the method. Plus, you need to declare your students' arraylist as a member variable and initialize it :

```
public class TextUI
{
     private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
     private Scanner myScanner;
     private LabClass labClass;

     public TextUI()
     {
         myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         createLabClass();
     }
     .......
}
```

Comment: You need to declare the arrayList everytime you want to use a method held inside the arrayList?

Also, that hasn't done anything. I get the same error.

Comment: @J.Brown Not quite, you want to create the ArrayList at the class level. You only need to do that once, and then you're able to do `students.add(student)` in your enrollStudent method

Comment: I said that you must declare the arrayList as a MEMBER VARIABLE.

Comment: So how do I create the ArrayList at class level? You'll have to excuse me if I'm making you repeat yourself, I'm trying to get my brain around this.

Comment: Okay so, I've managed to get the private void addStudent to compile, but now I'm getting an error when I try and call addStudent from a different part of the same class.

Comment: I'm not sure what a member variable is, where exactly do I need to declare it?

Comment: A member variable is declared inside a class definition but outside any of its methods. Got it ?

Comment: Okay, sorted. So now how do I call the addStudent(Student newStudent) method from another method in the same class?

Comment: one more thing : where do you call the addStudent method ?

Comment: Inside the private void execute(int command) method. Basically, what I'm doing is creating a text interface that takes an int as an input, the int then relates to a method, one of the methods being addStudent(). So I needed to first create the addStudent() and then call the method from another place in the class.

Comment: So you are displaying a menu with the displayMenu() method, and the user chooses an option that gets stored in the command variable. Then you are calling the execute() method with the option that the user has chosen as a parameter.

Comment: So you need to add another condition check in the execute() method to check if command == 2, then call addStudent() .

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I've done that already, but now it's giving me the same error as before. If I call addStudent() it says it's expecting a parameters and if I call addStudent(Student newStudent) it says ')' expected.

Comment: Show me the code, in which you are invoking the addStudent() method.

Comment: private void execute(int command)
    {
        if(command == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Terminating program...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        if(command == 1)
        {
            labClass.getLabClass();
        }
        else
        if(command == 2)
        {
            addStudent(Student newStudent);
        }
        else

Comment: post it above, not here in the comments.

Comment: Posted it. I'm really not getting any of this.

Comment: check the Edit, & try again.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you've changed?

Comment: I understand how to call the methods. What's annoying me is that I can't figure out how to call the methods that require input.

Comment: Retrieve user input inside the addStudent() method.

Comment: But how am I supposed to retrieve user input when the method is asking for a Student object? I can't do myScanner.nextStudent(), what should I do instead?

Comment: you need to retrieve your student's infos one by one... for the example, if a student has a 'name' String property, you should use myScanner.nextLine(); if it has an 'age' int property you should use nextInt() and so on... post the code of the Student class above.

Comment: So what's the point in even having the student class if I need to reinput all the information again?

Comment: The student class is the model, it's what keeping it all together.